# Concerns discussing 'illegal' activities in a job interview

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, xss, vulnerability

Before I begin, I say 'illegal' because I guess the law is somewhat sketchy around the topic and that topic is XSS research.  Apparently people have been taken to court over it and UK law does have a section that covers it but still.

So, I have an interview coming up for my placement year as a penetration tester.  This morning I identified XSS vulnerabilities on 9 different websites without permission to search for those vulnerabilities.  They have all been verified and they're all reflected XSS.

Is there any way to slip this into the interview to prove that I'm sort of actively researching?  I mean, for everything else, I actively research in my own environments but that's somewhat difficult to do with XSS.

Any advice on how or even if I should bring this up?

Comment: So since you had no permission don't mention this. You could however suggest that you can give them a "taster" of what you can do and "stumble" upon one of those XSS while you do that. But make sure you don't go "Heh, there's one!".

Comment: I agree with @FlorinCoada

Comment: You're seriously asking if you should mention to a potential employer that you respect no ethical or legal obligations and that you're going to be a liability for them? Seriously? By the way, there's a workplace StackExchange for employment questions.

Comment: @FlorinCoada, depending on the company Sevaara is interviewing for, actively hacking without permission of the site owner would have the opposite effect...

Comment: I'm just saying, laws were passed recently to allow GCHQ to actively hack with no consequences.  Besides, reflected XSS research is barely anything big.  Well, not in my eyes.  To me it just proves that I know how to XSS, what I look for and how I start crafting.  I mean, if I'd busted out a full set of tools and rooted 15 servers then yeah, don't mention it.  But for this, I reckon I could just reword it.

Comment: @GCHQ is [self-censored, because politics], but we're not here to do politics. The proper way to display your skills is to use challenge websites set for that purpose, get businesses to agree to you doing a free review of their security to build up your portfolio, or setup test environments and record yourself successfully attacking in those controlled environments.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are undergoing a polygraph examination (in which case you will have already disclosed pertinent answers such as 'have you hacked a system' and are merely being tested on truthfulness of your disclosures) then take the American attitude of anti-self incrimination (the 5th Amendment to the US Constitution).

During your interview, simply explain that you have researched x number of active vulnerabilities and are working with those clients to path their systems (or whatever you SLA with the 'researched into' companies is).

If you have indeed verified the XSS bugs and the companies have patched them, then look into disclosing them completely or at the very least look into having the companies you did the pentests for write you a recommendation letter confirming that you did the work.

Also, there is a distinction between legality and morality. The concept of what is legal and illegal is rather cut and dry (although judicial systems still debate this) whereas the sense of morality is highly subjective.